# How do i fix these "node-pre-gyp" error with scratch-www?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have no idea what is going on, this is too long for me to understand. (this was while running npm install)
Logs:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! make: Går till katalogen ”/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build”
npm ERR!   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
npm ERR!   COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o
npm ERR! make: Lämnar katalogen ”/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build”
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@20.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v115-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v115-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.0 and node@20.11.0 (node-v115 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.0/canvas-v2.9.0-node-v115-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.6.0 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:178,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/backend/Backend.h:6,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/backend/Backend.cc:1:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:23: error: ‘AccessorSignature’ is not a member of ‘v8’
npm ERR!    55 | typedef v8::Local<v8::AccessorSignature> Sig;
npm ERR!       |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:40: error: template argument 1 is invalid
npm ERR!    55 | typedef v8::Local<v8::AccessorSignature> Sig;
npm ERR!       |                                        ^
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/backend/Backend.h:6,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/backend/Backend.cc:1:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h: In function ‘void Nan::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::Local<v8::String>, Nan::GetterCallback, Nan::SetterCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, Nan::imp::Sig)’:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan.h:2544:19: error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>&, void (*&)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&), void (*&)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<void>&), v8::Local<v8::Object>&, v8::AccessControl&, v8::PropertyAttribute&, Nan::imp::Sig&)’
npm ERR!  2544 |   tpl->SetAccessor(
npm ERR!       |   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
npm ERR!  2545 |       name
npm ERR!       |       ~~~~         
npm ERR!  2546 |     , getter_
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~~~~~      
npm ERR!  2547 |     , setter_
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~~~~~      
npm ERR!  2548 |     , obj
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~          
npm ERR!  2549 |     , settings
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~~~~~~     
npm ERR!  2550 |     , attribute
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~    
npm ERR!  2551 |     , signature);
npm ERR!       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~   
npm ERR! In file included from /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-function.h:15,
npm ERR!                  from /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8.h:33,
npm ERR!                  from /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/node.h:73,
npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:58,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/backend/Backend.h:6,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/backend/Backend.cc:1:
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-template.h:809:8: note: candidate: ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::AccessorGetterCallback, v8::AccessorSetterCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, v8::SideEffectType, v8::SideEffectType)’
npm ERR!   809 |   void SetAccessor(
npm ERR!       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-template.h:814:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 7 from ‘Nan::imp::Sig’ {aka ‘int’} to ‘v8::SideEffectType’
npm ERR!   814 |       SideEffectType getter_side_effect_type = SideEffectType::kHasSideEffect,
npm ERR!       |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-template.h:816:8: note: candidate: ‘void v8::ObjectTemplate::SetAccessor(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::AccessorNameGetterCallback, v8::AccessorNameSetterCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::AccessControl, v8::PropertyAttribute, v8::SideEffectType, v8::SideEffectType)’
npm ERR!   816 |   void SetAccessor(
npm ERR!       |        ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/user/.cache/node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/v8-template.h:821:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 7 from ‘Nan::imp::Sig’ {aka ‘int’} to ‘v8::SideEffectType’
npm ERR!   821 |       SideEffectType getter_side_effect_type = SideEffectType::kHasSideEffect,
npm ERR!       |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! make: *** [canvas.target.mk:161: Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o] Fel 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:209:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=9" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v115"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=9 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v115' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-91-generic
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/Skrivbord/scratch-www-c01438be0bc1a0c07ec854e756ff6442b6e034be/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.8
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/user/.npm/_logs/2024-02-01T13_36_38_915Z-debug-0.log
```

I am on Linux Mint.

How to hopefully reproduce:
Download the source from [this repository.](https://github.com/scratchfoundation/scratch-www/tree/c01438b)
Now try to run it and then it will spew out a error similar to this.
Note: some stuff is in Swedish, you might not understand it.

Comment: If this happened on an already existing project- remove package-lock.json- it helped me. ;)